# Loop through array of objects, if any prop in object has a specific sub-string in its value. Push that object into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

```
    // Array to loop through
    var array = [{team: 'nets',
                  description:'hello nets'},
                 {team:'knicks',
                  description:' the new york knicks'}];

    // Function to check
    var checkObj = function(arr,value) {

    var found = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].description.substring(value)) {
            found.push(arr[i]);
        }

        return found;
    }
    };

    // Try looking to see if 'knicks' exist in array
    var knicksMatch = checkObj(array,'knicks');
```

knicksMatch returns to me an array with the 1st object which is the 'nets' object even though I typed in something completely different.

Comment: [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) takes indices as argument not the string. You are using the wrong method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong method to check if the string exists in the description:

Instead of:

```
if (arr[i].description.substring(value)) {
```

You need to use:

```
if (arr[i].description.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
```

Also, you need to `return` the result *after* the `for` loop has finished.

```js
// Array to loop through
var array = [
  { team: 'nets', description: 'hello nets' },
  { team: 'knicks', description: ' the new york knicks' }
];

// Function to check
var checkObj = function(arr, value) {
  var found = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].description.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
      found.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return found;
};

// Try looking to see if 'knicks' exist in array
var knicksMatch = checkObj(array, 'knicks');

console.log(knicksMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
arr[i].description.substring(value)
```

You can do this:

```
 var array = [{team: 'nets',
              description:'hello nets'},
             {team:'knicks',
              description:' the new york knicks'}];

// Function to check
var checkObj = function(arr,value) {

var found = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i].description.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
           found.push(arr[i]);
       }           
   }
   return found;
};

// Try looking to see if 'knicks' exist in array
var knicksMatch = checkObj(array,'knicks');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use filter:

```
knicksMatch=array.filter(el=>el.description.includes("knicks"));
```

In your code you may replace *substring* with *includes*, substring isnt doing what youre expecting:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 0):

**Using the javascript Filter method.**

```
 var array = [{team: 'nets',
                      description:'hello nets'},
                     {team:'knicks',
                      description:' the new york knicks'}];


    function filter(str){
     return array.filter(function(item){
      return (item.description.indexOf(str)>-1)
     })
    }

    console.log(filter('new'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Array to loop through
    var array = [{team: 'nets',
                  description:'hello nets'},
                 {team:'knicks',
                  description:' the new york knicks'}];

    // Function to check
    var checkObj = function( array , value ) {

    var found = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ( array[i].description.indexOf( value ) != -1 ) {
               found.push( array[i] );
            }

       }
       return found;
    };

    var knicksMatch = checkObj(array,'knicks');
    console.log(knicksMatch );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].description.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        found.push(arr[i]);
    }

    return found;
}
```

String.prototype.indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.